# Get EditText Control from ListView in Xamarin Studio with C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin Studio with C#.

I have added **EditText** control in **listview** adapter. And this list is dynamically populated.

Now I want to get value of all EditText  in **activity** class. How I can achieve this?

`public class PRDeptHeadApprovalDetailAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        List items;
        Activity context;

```
    public PRDeptHeadApprovalDetailAdapter(Activity context, List<PRDeptHeadApprovalDetailAdapterInformation> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    public override string this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position].ToString(); }
    }


    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];
        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is supplied
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PRDeptHeadApprovalDetailAdapter, null);
        // set view properties to reflect data for the given row
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lbltdPermNo).Text = item.lbltdPermNo;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lbltdItemName).Text = item.lbltdItemName;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lbltdJustification).Text = item.lbltdJustification;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lbltdSrce).Text = item.lbltdSrce;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lbltdQuantity).Text = item.lbltdQuantity;
        EditText txtApproveQuantity = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.lbltdApproveQuantity);
        txtApproveQuantity.Text = item.lbltdApproveQuantity;
        // return the view, populated with data, for display
        return view;
    }
}`
```

Comment: you have edit text as listview row?

Comment: Yes, I am using EditText in listview for getting data from user.

Comment: can you post your adapter code??

Comment: I am try to past my adapter class but here is not allowing becoz of more character. But I use same this adapter class check URL.
[link]http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/[link]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At First Create Object of your `ListView Adapter`

```
titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter();
```

Then you able to get Each position of the `listview EditText` Value by the `position` of the list-view

```
View view = titleAdapter .getView(position, null, null);
EditText edittext= (EditText ) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_id_here);
edittext.getText();
```

Comment: Your post is helpful. But I'm not get solution.
without parameter constructor not accessing. Such as
`titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter();`
And if I use
`EditText edittext = (EditText)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lbltdApproveQuantity);`
It is not getting **EditText**. :(
I am using Xamarin Studio with C#.

Comment: How I can paste... becoz here is not allowing... :(

Comment: I am edit your post. it help to get your answer. This Solution for android Native sdk.

Comment: Thank you very much Gafur.
I use same adapter class check URL.
[link]http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/[link]

Comment: Actually, my adapter class name is PRDeptHeadApprovalDetailAdapter. But I am using same technique in my mobile app.
And my requirement is that I filling listview using WCF and user enter some information then I get this information from listview and save in DB using WCF.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45705/discussion-between-md-abdul-gafur-and-mshoaiblibra)

Comment: PRDeptHeadApprovalDetailAdapter object= new PRDeptHeadApprovalDetailAdapter(this, List<item>);

listView.setAdapter(object);

for(int i=0 ; i< object.getCount() ; i++)
{
View view = object.getView(position, null, null);
EditText edittext= (EditText ) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_id_here);
edittext.getText();
}

Comment: Yes, this post is helpful. Thank you

Comment: Abdul, Your post was very helpful for me. But I I'm facing issue that I'm getting old value from EditView. But I need new value which enter user. Plz help me in this issue.

Comment: @mshoaiblibra did you find a solution on getting the old value from EditView?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtKeyItem"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtValue"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

//**********************************************************************************//
ListView lstItems = (ListView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lstInvoiceItems);
var v = (ViewGroup)lstItems;
            factureItems.Clear();
            KeyValuePair<string, string> items = new KeyValuePair<string, int>();
            for(int i = 0; i < v.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                    var linear = (ViewGroup)(v.GetChildAt(i));
                    var editTextKey = (EditText)linear.GetChildAt(0);
                    var EditTextValue = (EditText)linear.GetChildAt(1);
                    item.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(editTextKey.Text,EditTextValue.Text)); 
            }
```