# Get Value from EditText in ListView in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin Studio with C#.

Actually, I create one custom listView and in this listview I'm using one EditText field for getting information from user. And this listview dynamically generate base response of WCF.
This WCF connect with our DB use for getting and retrieve data.

Currently, I'm using below line of code.

```
for(int i=0 ; i< listAdapter.Count ; i++) 
{ 
    View view = listAdapter.GetView(i, null, null); 
    EditText edittext= (EditText) view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lbltdApproveQuantity); 
    string str = edittext.Text; 
}
```

**Problem is: I'm getting Old Value not getting latest Value which user entered.**

Advance thanks for all experts. Waiting your response.

Comment: Can you paste a bigger portion of your code? This code is being implemented on which method/event?

Comment: Kindly, check below thread. It's also my create thread for same issue with more information:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252308/get-edittext-control-from-listview-in-xamarin-studio-with-c-sharp[link]